# How to sample 50 random files from my dataset witch each file having the same probabilty to be taken in shell script?

Tags: bash, shuffle, sampling, command-line-tool

does `find /mnt/Dataset/ -type f | shuf -n 50` is doing the trick?
Does `shuf` wait to count all the lines then do a random selection? Does `shuf` give the same probability to each line? Or should I use another tool?

Comment: @alecxs yes my dataset is a lot of videos `find -type f` should make each line a file right?

Comment: @alecxs can you be explicit and an example? I'm not sure to follow what you mean? my data don't have a `\n` in their file name and I can use `find -printf0` and `shuf -z` but that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: You can look at [the source of `shuf`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/shuf.c) to see how it works.

Comment: Maybe you will get some answers from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108581/how-to-randomly-sample-a-subset-of-a-file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random files selector in filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245105/random-files-selector-in-filesystem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are wondering how `shuf` works with the pipeline (wait for the pipeline to be finished or process data when it is available, you can write a test. The test will look like:

```
for ((i=0; i<20; i++)); do
  (printf "%s\n" {1..9}; sleep 0.1; echo 10) | shuf | tr '\n' ' '
  echo
done
```

This test is without the -n option and you want a larger sample to look at the averages. The next loop is better for testing

```
for ((i=0; i<10000; i++)); do
  (printf "%s\n" {1..9}; sleep 0.01; echo 10) | shuf | tr '\n' ' '
  echo
done > sample.txt
# Look for how often 10 is the last number on a line
grep -c "10 $" sample.txt
```

I also did a test:

```
cut -d " " -f1 sample.txt | sort | uniq -c
   1040 1
    985 10
    976 2
   1012 3
    981 4
    999 5
   1043 6
    974 7
    979 8
   1011 9
```

I did not check the distribution with the sample size, but it feels like a good random distribution.